# Single word for both rate of 'production' and 'consumption'

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm modelling a system and certain components can both *consume* and *produce* resources at a certain rate. Is there a common word that entails **rate of consumption and/or production**.

The closest word I can think of is *throughput* or *yield* but I'm not too sure that's correct.

Comment: It depends on the context  - production could be considered in some cases as negative consumption so in this case they are the same thing one being when the rate is negative

Comment: ***throughput***

Comment: Highly dependent on the specific field involved, meaningless in many.

Comment: ***Metabolism*** is a chemical reaction that can be measured in terms of both consumption and production of resource.

Answer (score 1):

The word *net* has the meaning of production minus consumption, although it's generally used as a modifier.  You might try *[net yield](http://www.investorwords.com/3268/net_yield.html)* or *[net rate](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/net-rate.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

Capacity.

Ah. I see I'm not allowed to post that single word. How about ... *flow*, then?

Answer (score 1):

In nature, the process you suggest would be digestion. Dan Bron's throughput is I think an excellent suggestion. Again though it depends on context. flybynite.